# Fetching data from moodle database

Tags: php, moodle

I am trying to query some data from the moodle database. I am using the data manipulation API. Here is my code. When I run it on the browser, i get a blank screen. i reall dont know what the $enrolids is. Is it an associative array or what. Even when I try create an associative array, I still get a blank screen.

```
<?php
require_once("../config.php");
$userid=$_GET['userid'];
//Get the enrolids from the mdl_user_enrolments table
$enrolids=$DB->get_records_sql('SELECT enrolid FROM {user_enrolments} WHERE userid=?', array($userid));
echo $enrolids['enrolid'];
?>
```

Will appreciate the help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:
To anyone with the same problem. Here is the solution.
Moodle is object oriented. Meaning, the queries made, return an Array of stdclass objects i.e:

```
Array ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [status] => 0 [enrolid] => 5 [userid] => 3 [timestart] => 0 [timeend] => 2147483647 [modifierid] => 0 [timecreated] => 0 [timemodified] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [status] => 0 [enrolid] => 6 [userid] => 3 [timestart] => 0 [timeend] => 2147483647 [modifierid] => 0 [timecreated] => 0 [timemodified] => 0 ) )
```

Use the -> notation to fetch whatever value you desire i.e If the above array is stored in a variable e.g. $arr, do the following to access status for example

```
$arr[1]->status;
```

CHEERS....